# What dose 'Bi' mean in BiConsumer/BiFunction/BiPredicate?

Tags: java

Not well in English.
Just wonder, in java's two-arity functional interfaces, What dose Bi mean?

Comment: It just means "2" in the context of arity, i.e. the function, predicate and consumer have 2 arguments. See javadocs: `This is the two-arity specialization of {@link Function}.`

Comment: `The English prefixes bi-, derived from Latin, and its Greek counterpart di- both mean “two.”` [link](http://membean.com/wrotds/bi-twice)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: I voted to leave it open; it's a reasonable thing for a java developer to be curious about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary, which means double. BiConsumer takes two, instead of one parameter per call.

The same goes for all other Bi-prefixed classes in the java.util.function package.